# adding price with radio button in html

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to set different price (including tax) for each payment method below.
[image]

when user choose the payment method (radio button), it will show the the price on cart total column. This is what I'm doing in my view.

```
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="text-center">Choose Payment Method</h3>
                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn bg-payment btn-primary form-check-label full-width-height">
                    <input name="pay" value="credit_card" class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off" required> Credit Card
                  </label><br><br>

                  <label class="btn bg-payment btn-primary form-check-label full-width-height">
                    <input name="pay" value="qris" class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off" required> Qris
                  </label><br><br>

                  <label class="btn bg-payment btn-primary form-check-label full-width-height">
                    <input name="pay" value="bank_transfer_bni" class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off" required> Bank Transfer BNI
                  </label><br><br>

                  <label class="btn bg-payment btn-primary form-check-label full-width-height">
                    <input name="pay" value="bank_transfer_permata" class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off" required> Bank Transfer Permata
                  </label><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" required>
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">I agree with <a href="#">terms & conditions</a></label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

most of tutorial that i found are using radio button value to set the output. but since I'm using the value for the next step, I'm looking for another solution to do this. is there anything i can do or any reference that similar to my problem?

Comment: May be you want something like this https://codepen.io/diler/pen/KKwjyqE

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a function that changes the fee based on the radio input selected, update the inner html of your fee element, then just apply that to each payment methods onclick event.

The function:

```
  function selectPayment(type) {
    let fee;
    if(type === 'Credit Card') {
      fee = 5;
    }
    if(type === 'Qris') {
      fee = 10;
    }
    ((REPEAT FOR EACH PAYMENT TYPE))
    ((CALCULATE TOTAL HERE))
    document.getElementById('fee').innerHTML = "Fee: $" + fee;
  }
```

Then apply that function to each radio element's onclick.

```
<label class="btn bg-payment btn-primary form-check-label full-width-height">
    <input name="pay" value="credit_card" class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"  onclick="selectPayment('Credit Card')" required> Credit Card </label>
```

Here's a basic pen doing just that:
https://codepen.io/sted6/pen/rNxvRdm

Obviously you need to adjust it to render the fee however you want and set the correct amounts and what not, but this general methodology should work.